# Uncaught ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration '__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__' before initialization

Tags: reactjs

I created a a React. application and it is working, but if I try to add provider and store from redux , I get a blanc page with this error in the console. Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT' before initialization but showing that everything is working fine in the terminal. Please let me know what could be wrong.

my index.js code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import App from "./App";
import store from "./redux/store";
import Modal from "react-modal";

Modal.setAppElement("#root");

ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
<App />
</Provider>
   

    

    
,
  
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```